# Search in list using PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#

I am trying to create dynamic predicate so that it can be used against a list for filtering

I have a class:

```
public  class MyClass
    {
        public  string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to search in my data by Name Or Address, and Name or Address Like input(ex: input=t%g).
Name Like input Or Address Like input

Here is my helper

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> StringLike<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector1, string pattern)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        var predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();
        var parts = pattern.Split('%');
        if (parts.Length == 1) // not '%' sign
        {
            predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s) == pattern);
            predicate1 = predicate1.And(s => selector1.Compile()(s) == pattern);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                string p = parts[i];
                if (p.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).StartsWith(p));
                        predicate1 = predicate1.And(s=>selector1.Compile()(s).StartsWith(p));
                    }
                    else if (i == parts.Length - 1)
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).EndsWith(p));
                        predicate1 = predicate1.And(s => selector1.Compile()(s).EndsWith(p));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        predicate = predicate.And(s => selector.Compile()(s).Contains(p));
                        predicate1 = predicate1.And(s => selector1.Compile()(s).Contains(p));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        var test = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Or(predicate, predicate1));
        return test;
    }
```

In main function:

```
var expr = ExpressionHelper.StringLike<myclass>(x => x.Name,x=>x.Address, text);
```

data = data.Where(expr.Compile()).ToList();

I run into the following exception:

```
The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication1.Program+MyClass,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication1.Program+MyClass,System.Boolean]'.
```

Please help me.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What would not work if you used .Contains()?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Thanks you, but Contrains() is not enought.I want to use my helper in linq as Like in SQL.(I don't speak much English, i'm from Viet Nam)